# ScreenOverlay orientation

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would like to generate a dynamic legend such that individual icons in the legend can change freely without compromising the rest of the legend, but I am having some trouble with spacing. Right now I am using separate screen overlays for each element in the legend and spacing them with an offset on screenXY using percentage. This works well with one screen resolution, but the legend looks strange when you stretch or condense the google earth window. I would like to use pixels to make the legend statically space the icons, but I have no way of knowing how tall the window will be and therefore cannot guess at what height I should begin the legend. Is there a way to nest ScreenOverlays so that I can set a ScreenOverlay at a percentage, but inside that ScreenOverlay statically space individual icons? Is there another approach that does not involve creating a single image for the legend?

I have tried simply nesting the Screen Overlays, but no luck. I also cannot find documentation on multiple icons in a single ScreenOverlay.

```
<ScreenOverlay>
  <name>icon1</name>
  <Icon>
    <href>https://url/here.png</href>
  </Icon>
  <overlayXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  <screenXY x=".05" y=".75" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  <rotationXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  <size x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
</ScreenOverlay>
<ScreenOverlay>
  <name>icon2</name>
  <Icon>
    <href>https://url/here.png</href>
  </Icon>
  <overlayXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  <screenXY x=".05" y=".72" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  <rotationXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  <size x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
</ScreenOverlay>
```

Using fractions works, but it does not scale well when the user stretches or shrinks the window. It will either squish together or it will spread to far apart. Pixels would be better if I could tell how tall the screen was from the kml.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the layout and spacing of multiple ScreenOverlays in relation to eachother, and not have it change with screen size, then you are correct that you'll need to use Pixel units for the positioning. There's no way to nest ScreenOverlays, but you should be able to stack them so long as each element is a predictable size.  For example, you might have 3 icons each 100px tall, and to have them stacked in the bottom left corner, the first one would be positioned at x=0, y=0, the second one at x=0, y=100, and the third at x=0, y=200.  It's best practice to minimize screen overlays, to minimize how much of the map you cover up, so hopefully it won't be so tall that most screen sizes should show the whole thing.